# AVPlayerItemVideoOutput never gets a pixelBuffer

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, opengl-es, avfoundation

I've been expanding my testing on my video rendering code and noticed something unusual during testing with AVPlayerItemVideoOutput.  In trying to test my rendering code I check for new pixel buffers using hasNewPixelBufferForItemTime.

While testing, this method never returns yes.  But the rendering code works in my app just fine using the same setup, rendering frames to openGL textures.

I setup a github project with the very basics showing the error.  In the app you can load the video by tapping the button (Not loaded immediately to avoid any conflict with the test).  This proves at least the video loads and plays.

The project also has test, that attempts to setup the AVPlayerItemVideoOutput and check for new pixel buffers.  This test always fails, but I can't see what I'm doing wrong, or why the exact same steps work in my own app.

[The GitHub project is here](https://github.com/seriouscyrus/AVPlayerTest).

And this is the test method to peruse:

```
#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface AVPlayerTestTests : XCTestCase

@end

@implementation AVPlayerTestTests

- (void)setUp {
    [super setUp];
    // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.
}

- (void)tearDown {
    // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
    [super tearDown];
}

- (void) testAVPlayer
{
    NSURL *fileURL = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:self.class] URLForResource:@"SampleVideo_1280x720_10mb" withExtension:@"mp4"];
    AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:fileURL];
    [self keyValueObservingExpectationForObject:playerItem
                                        keyPath:@"status" handler:^BOOL(id  _Nonnull observedObject, NSDictionary * _Nonnull change) {
                                            AVPlayerItem *oPlayerItem = (AVPlayerItem *)observedObject;
                                            switch (oPlayerItem.status) {
                                                case AVPlayerItemStatusFailed:
                                                {
                                                    XCTFail(@"Video failed");
                                                    return YES;
                                                }
                                                    break;
                                                case AVPlayerItemStatusUnknown:
                                                    return NO;
                                                    break;
                                                    case AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay:
                                                {
                                                    return YES;
                                                }
                                                default:
                                                    break;
                                            }
                                        }];
    AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
    NSDictionary *pbOptions = @{
                                (NSString *)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey        : [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA],
                                (NSString *)kCVPixelBufferIOSurfacePropertiesKey    : [NSDictionary dictionary],
                                (NSString *)kCVPixelBufferOpenGLESCompatibilityKey  : @YES
                                };
    AVPlayerItemVideoOutput *output = [[AVPlayerItemVideoOutput alloc] initWithPixelBufferAttributes:pbOptions];
    XCTAssertNotNil(output);
    [self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:100 handler:nil];
    if (playerItem.status == AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay) {
        [playerItem addOutput:output];
        player.rate = 1.0;
        player.muted = YES;
        [player play];
        CMTime vTime = [output itemTimeForHostTime:CACurrentMediaTime()];
        // This is what we're testing
        BOOL foundFrame = [output hasNewPixelBufferForItemTime:vTime];
        XCTAssertTrue(foundFrame);
        if (!foundFrame) {
            // Cycle over for ten seconds
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                sleep(1);
                vTime = [output itemTimeForHostTime:CACurrentMediaTime()];
                foundFrame = [output hasNewPixelBufferForItemTime:vTime];
                if (foundFrame) {
                    NSLog(@"Got frame at %i", i);
                    break;
                }
                if (i == 9) {
                    XCTFail(@"Failed to acquire");
                }
            }
        }

    }
}


@end
```

EDIT 1 : This seems to be a bug and I've filed a Radar

Comment: Hey! Do you have the Radar number on this? I'd like to reference it in the Radar I'm about to open up, as I have a similar issue that stems from the same problem. Thanks!